# SAS Convert $50. char string to YYYYMM

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that contains a field that is $50. char
Example value = 6/1/2015 0:00:00

I am trying to get a field from that dataset to store a YYYYMM value from that text string.

So for this example I need 201506

I know it's possible; but cannot seem to get it to work with anything

Currently have the following which gets me a lot closer.

```
 data a;
 set a.dataset;
 yearmon = input(date,anydtdtm20.);
 format yearmon datetime19;
 run;
```

This gets me 01JUN2015:00:00:00
I tried to change yearmon to yearmon = input(put(date, anydtdtme20.), yymmd.);
and remove the format line.  But that just gives me a blank value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `input` function (and not input from a text file etc.), you can ask it to truncate for you.

Then use the format `yymmn6.` (`n` means no separator):

```
data test;
  dtvar = '6/1/2015 0:00:00';
  x = input(dtvar,mmddyy10.);
  format x yymmn6.;
  put x=;
run;
```

If you want a character value and not a formatted numeric, add a `put` step.

```
data test;
  dtvar = '6/1/2015 0:00:00';
  x = put(input(dtvar,mmddyy10.),yymmn6.);
  put x=;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  However, my ultimate goal is to take that value:  201506 and concatenate it with another field to make up an ID.   The other field is a character field $20. char  (example:  12345678909876543210)    I tried to use ID = catt(Field1, x);  but the result was 1234567890987654321020240   somehow the x turns into 20240 using the catt function.  Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to `put` the date variable to the format, rather than just formatting it in the datastep.

Comment: Thank you. I actually got it to work with ID = catt(Field1, put(x, yymmn6.));

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `datepart()` function to get the date component of your datetime value :

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  yearmon = input(date,anydtdtm20.) ;
  dt = datepart(yearmon) ;
  format yearmon datetime19. dt yymmn6. ;
run ;
```

Comment: thank you. So I'm still at a loss as to how I will get YYYYMM out of this.  Ultimately I am looking for the result of this example to give me 201506